# How do I read n bytes from file descriptor 0 to a file? Bytes can be any value

Tags: stdin

I need to read a specific number of bytes from `fd0` and write them to a file. The bytes can have any value.

I assume I can't use `dd` since it stops at the `EOF` byte. Using `if=/dev/stdin` won't work since my `fd0` isn't the keyboard.

Comment: why would you assume `dd` stops on an EOF byte? Did you try it? Can you [edit] to show what you did and what happened?

Comment: There's no such thing as "the EOF byte"

Comment: File descriptor 0 is otherwise known as "stdin". `/dev/stdin` is a (most likely) a symbolic link to `/proc/self/fd/0` where `/proc/self` is a symbolic link that resolves differently for each process.  Long story short, `/dev/stdin` will resolve to whatever file descriptor 0 is for the process resolving it.  If `/dev/stdin` is somehow different for you, you can always use `/proc/self/fd/0`.

Comment: EOF isn't a signal and it isn't "emitted" either.  It's just a condition on a file descriptor.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this misunderstanding, I thought EOF is a specific byte, which would make sending binary data difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dd (and many other unix commands) default to taking input from stdin when no input file is supplied.

stdin doesn't have to be a keyboard, and frequently isn't.

The dd command is specifically designed to copy binary data.  And even if it wasn't, `EOF` is not a byte in unix.  It is a condition on a file descriptor indicating there is no more data from that source.

From a keyboard (or more to the point, a tty), the <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> control character is not EOF, but (by default) causes the tty to enter EOF condition, similar to how <kbd>Backspace</kbd> causes a character to be removed from the input buffer.  Note that this only has meaning when the tty is in cooked mode rather than raw mode, and the control character for EOF can be changed in the tty.

A perfectly workable solution to read n bytes (where n is a number) would be `dd count=1 bs=n`

Note that if you are typing multiple lines from a keyboard or there is a pause before all the data is sent, dd will interpret this as a block boundary.  Adding `iflag=fullbock` will force dd to wait for the full 10 bytes before ending the block.

Comment: Except that if you try e.g. `dd count=1 bs=10` with input from the terminal, and type `foo<newline>`, it only copies four bytes. Or if you do something like `(echo foo; sleep .1; echo abcdefghijklmn) |dd count=1 bs=10` it again copies only four bytes.

Comment: It is probably reading that as a block.  You could try reversing it with `dd bs=1 count=10`

Comment: Added a fix to the answer for partial blocks.